# How to remove upper menu in settings.apk?

Tags: android, xml, apk, settings

I have a android 6.0 smartphone Gretel a7, and i want to edit it's Settings.apk. So, i want to remove upper menu (see picture) and to make ability to go back to my launcher app by pressing the home button. Also i have already cleared my dashboard in main settings menu by editing file res/xml/dasboard-categories.xml (now there are onle wi-fi and bluetooth items in it).

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0oTx.jpg)

So can you tell me how to remove upper menu and to make ability to go back to my launcher app by pressing "home"? Here are my decompiled settings.rar and settings.apk - https://nofile.io/f/RUhg7taZmTe/Settings.rar and [Settings.apk](https://nofile.io/f/a01CH72zoP4/Settings.apk)

Here is my  dashboard-settings.xml file from /res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dashboard-categories
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<dashboard-category 
    android:id="@id/wireless_section" 
    android:title="@string/header_category_wireless_networks" 
    android:key="@string/category_key_wireless">

    <dashboard-tile 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_wireless" 
         android:id="@id/wifi_settings" 
         android:title="@string/wifi_settings_title" 
         android:fragment="com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings" />

    <dashboard-tile 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_hetcomm" 
         android:id="@id/hetcomm_settings" 
         android:title="@string/hetcom_setting_title">

         <intent 
            android:action="com.android.settings.HETCOMM_SETTINGS" />
    </dashboard-tile>

    <dashboard-tile 
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth" 
         android:id="@id/bluetooth_settings" 
         android:title="@string/bluetooth_settings_title" 
         android:fragment= 
              "com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings"   />
</dashboard-category>
</dashboard-categories>
```

And here is bluetooth_settings.xml from /res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/bluetooth_settings"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And here is my bluetooth_device_settings.xml from /res/layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
     android:gravity="center" 
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <fragment 
     android:id="@id/bluetooth_fragment_settings" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     class="com.android.settings.bluetooth.DeviceProfilesSettings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Do not attach the whole project jar.

Comment: thanks for your reply. There are many xml files in decompiled settings...see [link](http://oi65.tinypic.com/fxtikl.jpg)

Comment: Just post the relevant code. No one is going to make extra efforts to go through all files if you only can't do that.

Comment: i've added it in my question